# Unity "Assertion failed on expression: 'go.IsActive()'" error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting these error messages whenever I turn off my program in unity and its mostly harmless, but I think is might sometimes cause problems and its really annoying. I tried fixing it but I don't know much about this and I couldn't find anything online. The code responsible for this problem goes as follows.

```cs
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
        {
            ColPH = col.name;
            InfoPH = GameObject.Find(ColPH);
            info = InfoPH.GetComponent<Info>();
            if(info.Ground == true)
            {
                Touch = false;
            }
        }
```

The line of code that I think is causing the problems is `InfoPH = GameObject.Find(ColPH);` but I have no Idea how to fix this.

I tried rewriting this and making small changes but its super pimple and very similar to other lines of code that work perfectly fine and the error messages are cryptic. I think this is caused by the program trying to access info while the program is shutting down but I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace :

```
 ColPH = col.name;
 InfoPH = GameObject.Find(ColPH);
```

by

```
InfoPH.gameObject
```

Also, assuming that Touch is true by default, you can replace

```
if(info.Ground == true)
{
    Touch = false;
}
```

by

```
Touch = !info.Ground
```